# How to generate a single diff from multiple changesets using mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a set of changes and I added a changeset in past which has changeset number, for example, 11001. I pushed this change to remote since somebody else needed it. Next, I continued developing my code and I had to pull changes from pushed by another user. So, I updated my branch and continued working. Later, I added more changes and made a commit with changeset number 11015.

Is there a way I can create a diff only with changesets 11001 and 11015? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have changeset(s) between 11001 and 11015 and want to ignore foreign work? DAG in question will be better a lot of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way from where you are is to locally copy rev 11015 to a direct child of 11001 using rebase:

```
hg rebase --keep -r 11015 -s 11001
```

then you can diff just the 2 revs directly as normal. You'll note that rev 11015 remains in place by virtue of --keep.

Don't attempt to push 11015. To that end you should prune it as soon as your done:

```
hg prune -r <#rev of the copy>
```

You'll need the evolve extension enabled (recommended anyway) to be able to use prune.

To make it even less likely that you'll attempt to push the copy, you can prune the copy immediately. You can still diff against it directly in tortoise if you enable the viewing of hidden changesets; or on the command line if you add --hidden to your usual diffing command.